# How to hide content that belongs to div but is displayed on another div?

Tags: html, css

I have table with fixed width. When there is some space it transfers to new line, but sometimes one word is too long and it steps to another div. I want to hide this part of text. [image: screenshot]

Comment: `overflow:hidden` - try that.

Comment: CSS overflow is what you are looking for: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

Comment: It's a shame you haven't shown your code as well _ then answers could be more accurate and helpful _ Try `overflow: hidden;` on the div

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following solution:

```css
.truncate-text {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*
    Use (if you want to truncate the text with three dots):
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  */
}
```

```html
<div class="truncate-text">
  longlonglonglongword
</div>
```

Here, out of all the CSS properties used for the class `truncate-text`, two are important, i.e., `overflow: hidden` and `text-overflow: ellipsis`.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/34gkx8vt/) is the link to the fiddle where is works fine.

Also here are a few references:

1. [overflow CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)
2. [text-overflow CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow)

I hope this is helpful enough.

Answer (score 0):

This will wrap your text within the div, even if your string is unbroken (which is what I assume you mean).

```
.wordwrap {  
   white-space: pre-wrap;      /* Webkit */    
   white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox */     
   white-space: -pre-wrap;     /* Opera <7 */    
   white-space: -o-pre-wrap;   /* Opera 7 */     
   word-wrap: break-word;      /* IE */ 
}
```

The problem is that you have a very long word. You can do as they said, with word-wrap: break-word; or you can hide the text.

You can use text-overflow, i.e:

```
p {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Where:

```
text-overflow: clip|ellipsis|string;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code

```css
table td {
  width: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

table td:hover {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<table border='1px' style="table-layout:fixed; width:20px;">
  <tr>
    <td>ddddsssssssssssssss</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

It will also help to see hidden text when you hover it.